# how to retrieve scmPollingLog from jenkins using json/xml api.?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to automate our team's build process.

I need to get the time stamp details of last svn refresh (considering our server polls automatically after every hour).

After trying few things, scmPollLog page seems to be give some helpful information. How can i fetch information in this page with xml or json api.

If the approach is not good, how can i get the last svn refresh details in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Jenkins (at least as of Jenkins 1.609.1 LTS) does not provide API access to the *scmPollLog*. But it's pretty easy to get this content with a little screen scraping. For example, in Python with requests and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scm_log_resp = requests.get('http://jenkins:8080/job/MYJOB/scmPollLog')
soup = BeautifulSoup(scm_log_resp.text, 'html.parser')
scm_log = soup.find(id='main-panel-content').pre
```